# Why doesn't :extend() compile with gulp-less?

Tags: less, gulp-less

I created an :extend expression following the LESS documentation. But gulp-less doesn't compile it.

What's wrong with these expressions?

```
html
{
    &:extend(body);
}

body
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

or

```
html:extends(body)
{
}

body
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to an outdated version of gulp-less

Try run this NPM command:

```
npm update gulp-less
```

It will update your package and should include all the latest functionality.

Comment: I have updated the latest version of gulp-less and still :extend is not working inside the nested scope but php less compiler takes it into account.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it has been a typo I gave. It shouldn't have read *extend**s***.

Probably that's been the cause for the upper version not working, too. Although I have written it correctly here, I might have misspelled it in my code.

Got that hint from the [gulp-less forum on GitHub](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2682).